# SBT - ignore compile errors (in tests)?

Tags: scala, build, compiler-errors, compilation, sbt

in my current SBT project `test:compile` reports all errors, but does *not* generate class files for the valid and unrelated tests.

It would be useful to run these tests separately.

Is it possible to force SBT to generate all class files it can?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then it can be boiled down to "how to do partial compilation?". I believe it is very complex thing, for example look at this http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Understanding-Recompilation.html

Comment: The short answer here is "no", but you might consider splitting your build up into several subprojects. Then you can do work in one subproject without its dependent subprojects needing to be compilable.

Comment: @Alexander: I think it's not as complex, because I don't want to recompile. If a file contains errors, don't produce a `.class` file. If it doesn't (and does not depend on an erroneous file), create one.

Comment: The criteria if one class depends on another is precisely quite complex. It can be inheritance, mixin, composition, implicits... And this dependency is not necessarily immediate, it can be  a chain.

Comment: aren't these dependencies already resolved by the scala compiler?